# Regex To Validate A Letter Range With Repeats

Tags: regex

I would like to validate a string for letters `A-Z`, `AA-ZZ`, `AAA-ZZZ`, and so on with a regex.  I know `[A-Z]` will validate the first case but what about the others.

```
A, B, C, D, E, .... Z
```

or

```
AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, .... ZZ
```

or

```
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, ... ZZZ
```

and so on...

Comment: Can you give some more examples of strings that should match and should not match? Do you know what the regular expression `[A-Z]` means? In particular it does  *not* match the string `"A-Z"`.

Comment: Should the pattern "AB" match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backreference, if your regex engine supports it:

```
^([A-Z])\1*$
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a pain to write, but if you want to match any number of letters and require them to all be the same letter, you could use something like this:

```
^(A+|B+|C+|D+ ...)$
```

and so on through the rest of the alphabet.

Comment: This can be improved with a back reference: ^([A-Z])\1+$

Comment: "Improved" is an interesting claim. ;-) It's no longer a true regular expression if you use backreferences, so some implementations won't process it; and the implementations that do have to use inefficient backtracking implementations. But it's true that it would work for many purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
^(\w)\1*$
```

You match any word character. If it is more than one char, it has to be the same.